# Plugin automatic compiling

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

Can anyone help me to find how to compile in an automatic way a plugin without the manual way in the terminal ?

thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7662/plugin-automatic-compiling/) by [djou07](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/969/djou07/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 78 on 2014-12-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [djou07](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/969/djou07/) on 2014-12-10**:
for more detail, I am trying to use genetic algorithms to evolve morphologies and controllers of many robots at the same time, so I am wondering how to compile a plugin of a new robot at run time simulation programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You'll have to use system calls, like [execv](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) to run cmake & make.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [djou07](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/969/djou07/) on 2014-12-12**:
Can you please give me further informations about system calls and an example how to use execv, (the link to execv do not work), thank you

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-12-16**:
Fixed the link. Searching google for execv will produce numerous results and examples.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Another idea: if your controller can be parameterized, then you could compile the plugin once and read in a separate parameter file for each test run.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-12-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [djou07](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/969/djou07/) on 2014-12-12**:
I did not program the controller yet, probably it will be a neural network, but I will try that out, thank you for your help